# Is it possible to do ORDER BY ABS(lat - $userLat) + ABS(lng - $userLng) with prisma

Tags: sql, prisma

I'm currently working on a side project where I need to order records based on the closest coordinates, but I haven't been able to find a way to achieve this using Prisma.

sql code I am trying to convert to Prisma:

```
SELECT * FROM Locations ORDER BY ABS(lat - $userLat) + ABS(lng - $userLng) ASC
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

some thing like the below will work:

```
const locations = await prisma.location.findMany({
  orderBy: {
    lat: {
      asc: true,
      cursor: {
        lat: userLat,
        lng: userLng
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I get the following error using that code: 
`Type '{ lat: { orderBy: string; cursor: { lat: string; lng: string; }; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Enumerable<LocationOrderByWithRelationInput> | undefined'.
  Types of property 'lat' are incompatible.
    Type '{ orderBy: string; cursor: { lat: string; lng: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'SortOrder | undefined'.`